# Density of $Y_a = sup_{t \in [\tau, \tau + a]}B_t$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider Brownian Motion $(B_t, t \geq 0)$ and $\tau = inf\left\{ t: B_t = x \right\} $ for $x > 0$. Find density of $Y_a = sup_{t \in [\tau, \tau + a]}B_t$. Could anybody give a hint how to approach this problem? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Is $Y_a$ not just distributed like $x + \sup_{t \in [0,a]} B_t$ by the strong Markov property? If this is the case then, by the reflection principle, we would have $Y_a \overset{d}{=} x + |B_a|$.

Comment: @Julius could you explain why does $Y_a$ distributed like x + $sup_{t\in[0, a]}B_t$?

Comment: $Y_a = \sup_{t \in [\tau , \tau+a]} B_t = \sup_{t \in [0,a]} B_{\tau+t} \overset{d}{=} \sup_{t \in [0,a]} (B_\tau + B'_t)$ by the strong Markov property, where $B'$ is a Brownian motion independent of $B$.

Comment: @Julius Oh, i understand it, thank you so much!